# Is there any English proverb parallel to any of these Persian proverbs?

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

There is a Persian proverb, which I would translate it as follow:

> **Whenever you catch a fish is fresh.**

Which is often used to suggest that it is never too late to do the right thing.

Comment: This would probably be best broken into two questions.

Comment: *Never too late to start*; *never too old to learn*.

Comment: There is an excellent book '1001 Persian-English Proverbs' by Simin Habibian that gives a Persian proverb, its literal translation to English, and then an idiomatic proverb in English with as close a corresponding meaning as possible.

Comment: Hi, Hooman, I edited your post to delete the second question. It is the guideline of Stack Exchange to ask one question per post. Please post another question if you need an answer to your second question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Better late than never](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/better-late-than-never) means exactly what it says.

> it is better for someone to ​arrive or do something late than not to ​arrive or do it at all - Cambridge Dictionaries Online

Answer (score 4):

[***It's***] ***Never too late*** [[***to do the right thing***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22it%27s+never+too+late+to+do+the+right%22&oq=%22it%27s+never+too+late+to+do+the+right%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...8068.9908.0.10707.12.9.0.0.0.0.466.1436.2-1j1j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..9.0.0.qJaYxlPsoSQ)] [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/fr/traduire/francais-anglais/il-n%27est-jamais-trop-tard-pour-bien-faire)

> ماهی را هروقت از آب بگیری تازه است
>
> māhi rā har vaqt az āb begiri tāze ast
>
> *Lit.* “Whenever you catch the fish it is fresh.”
>
> Never too late

[The University of Texas at Austin](https://sites.la.utexas.edu/persian_online_resources/proverbs/)

Answer (score 3):

Along the same lines as *better late than never*, you could say ***there's no time like the present***.